# How to decode a nested JSON struct with dynamic variable from API call

Tags: json, swift, codable

When calling to this specific API, one of the variables changes based on the results.

Example:

```
{
    "map": {
        "1945206": {
            "installBaseNUMB": 0,
            "serialNumber": "KB1",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

1945206 will change to another number and I don't know how to properly decode this.

My Codable struct is as follows:

```
struct Map: Codable {
    let the1945206: The1945206?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the1945206 = "1945206"
    }
}

struct The1945206: Codable {
    let installBaseNUMB: Int?
    let serialNumber, woStatus: String?
    let workOrderNumber: Int?
    let woNotes: [String]?
    let woParts: [WoPart]?
}
```

If 1945206 changes to another value, it breaks and won't show any results. How do I use a dynamic variable in decoding the data?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713638/swift-codable-with-dynamic-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root : Codable {
   let map: [String:The1945206]
}
```

---

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data)
print(res?.map.values)
```

---

```
{
    "map": {
        "1945204": {
            "installBaseNUMB": 0,
            "serialNumber": "KB1",
            ...
        },
        "1945205": {
            "installBaseNUMB": 0,
            "serialNumber": "KB1",
            ...
        },
        "1945206": {
            "installBaseNUMB": 0,
            "serialNumber": "KB1",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest setting different names than `The1945206` as it is less readable. I will use `MapElement` instead. If you know that map will have only one element, and you don't want to check what key is associated with this value, you can use computed property `var value:MapElement?` to get it. It returns an optional, because `let map:[String:MapElement]` dictionary can be empty.

```
let json = """
{
    "map": {
        "1945206": {
            "installBaseNUMB": 0,
            "serialNumber": "KB1"
        }
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Container: Codable {
    let map:[String:MapElement]

    var value:MapElement? {
        return map.values.first
    }
}

struct MapElement: Codable {
    let installBaseNUMB: Int
    let serialNumber: String
}

let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Container.self,from:json)
print(res?.value as Any)
```

---

Update:

If you want to use multiple `MapElement` you can change `var value:MapElement` to `var values:[MapElement]` like that:

```
struct Container: Codable {
    let map:[String:MapElement]

    var values:[MapElement] {
        return map.values
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that you are storing data as a dictionary so the order of elements is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct Install: Decodable {
    let installBaseNUMB: Int, serialNumber: String
}

let installData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:[String:Install]].self, from: jsonData2!)
let install = installData?.values.first?.values.first
```