# Swift Codable: encode structure with dynamic keys

Tags: swift, codable, encodable

I want to have the following JSON structure (fake example):

```
{
    "Admin" : 
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : "42"
    },
    "Sales" : 
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : "42"
    },
    "CEO" : 
    {
        "name" : "Peter",
        "age" : "52",
        "salary" : "100000"
    },
    "Janitor" : 
    {
        "name" : "Matthew",
        "age" : "22"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the structure if determined, but the name of the structure is dynamic.

How can I convert this to a Swift Codable struct?
Current try:

```
struct Positions: Codable
{
    var posDicts: [String: Position] = [:]
}

struct Position: Codable
{
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let salary: Int?
}
```

However, this would give the following:

```
"posDicts" : {
    "Admin" : 
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : "42"
    },
    "Sales" : 
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : "42"
    },
    "CEO" : 
    {
        "name" : "Peter",
        "age" : "52",
        "salary" : "100000"
    },
    "Janitor" : 
    {
        "name" : "Matthew",
        "age" : "22"
    }
}
```

I don't want the "posDicts" in the JSON.
What would be the best/simplest solution?

P.S.: related question regarding decodable [Swift Codable with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713638/swift-codable-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713638/swift-codable-with-dynamic-keys

Comment: @emrepun as you might have noticed, that is the exact same link I provide in my question. (iow: need more than that)

Comment: Sorry didn't catch that :/

Comment: Can happen, don't worry :D

Answer (score 2):

Rather than decoding

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Positions.self, from: data)
```

delete the `Positions` struct and decode

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Position].self, from: data)
```

---

To encode the dictionary accordingly declare it as

```
 var positions = [String:Position]()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Vadian is a good push in the right direction.
The solution was to encode the dictionary instead of a struct containing a dictionary.

As the original question is about encoding, the following is a complete solution:

```
var positions: [String: Position] = [:]
let json = try? encoder.encode(positions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encoding with dynamic keys seems like it's not supported at the moment.

I have used dictionary instead of encodable model that requires dynamic keys.

```
let dict = [dynamicKey: dynamicValue]
class MyModel: Encodable {
      someModelKey: dict
}
```