# Encode dictionary without adding the coding key enum in Swift

Tags: swift, encoding, codable, encodable

I want to encode a JSON that could be

```
{"hw1":{"get_trouble":true},"seq":2,"session_id":1}
```

or

```
{"hw2":{"get_trouble":true},"seq":3,"session_id":2}
```

the class for encoding looks like the following

```
class Request: Codable {
    let sessionId, seq:Int
    let content:[String:Content]
    
    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
        case sessionId = "session_id"
        case seq
        case content
    }
    
    init(sessionId:Int, seq:Int, content:[String:Content]) {
        self.sessionId = sessionId
        self.seq = seq
        self.content = content
    }
}

class Content:Codable{
    let getTrouble = true
    
    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case getTrouble = "get_trouble"
    }
}
```

how can I encode the request so that I can get the desired result? Currently, if I do

```
let request = Request(sessionId: session, seq: seq, content: [type:content])
let jsonData = try! encoder.encode(request)
```

I get

```
{"content":{"hw1":{"get_trouble":true}},"seq":2,"session_id":1}
```

and I don't want "content" inside the JSON. Already looked into 
[Swift Codable: encode structure with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729496/swift-codable-encode-structure-with-dynamic-keys)
and couldn't figure out how to apply in my use case

Comment: Do you also need decoding?

Comment: Yes, a similar request will need to be decoded. It could be
{"seq":1,"hw1":{"get_trouble":{"troubles":["alarm"],"error_code":0}}}
{"seq":1,"hw2":{"get_trouble":{"troubles":["bus"],"error_code":0}}}

Comment: The json in your comment doesn’t look even close to the types you have in your code.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn’t format it properly. The json in comment is the response which I need to decode later. Currently I am trying to encode the request that I need to send to the server and I’ll follow the same approach for decoding the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with almost all custom encoding problems, the tool you need is AnyStringKey (it frustrates me that this isn't in stdlib):

```
struct AnyStringKey: CodingKey, Hashable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    var stringValue: String
    init(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    init(_ stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue: stringValue) }
    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    init(stringLiteral value: String) { self.init(value) }
}
```

This just lets you encode and encode arbitrary keys. With this, the encoder is straightforward:

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self)
    for (key, value) in content {
        try container.encode(value, forKey: AnyStringKey(key))
    }
    try container.encode(sessionId, forKey: AnyStringKey("session_id"))
    try container.encode(seq, forKey: AnyStringKey("seq"))
}
```

This assumes you mean to allow multiple key/value pairs in Content. I expect you don't; you're just using a dictionary because you want a better way to encode. If Content has a single key, then you can rewrite it a bit more naturally this way:

```
// Content only encodes getTrouble; it doesn't encode key
struct Content:Codable{
    let key: String
    let getTrouble: Bool

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(["get_trouble": getTrouble])
    }
}

struct Request: Codable {
    // ...

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self)
        try container.encode(content, forKey: AnyStringKey(content.key))
        try container.encode(sessionId, forKey: AnyStringKey("session_id"))
        try container.encode(seq, forKey: AnyStringKey("seq"))
    }
}
```

Now that may still bother you because it pushes part of the Content encoding logic into Request. (OK, maybe it just bothers me.) If you put aside `Codable` for a moment, you can fix that too.

```
// Encode Content directly into container
extension KeyedEncodingContainer where K == AnyStringKey {
    mutating func encode(_ value: Content) throws {
        try encode(["get_trouble": value.getTrouble], forKey: AnyStringKey(value.key))
    }
}


struct Request: Codable {
    // ...

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self)

        // And encode into the container (note no "forKey")
        try container.encode(content)

        try container.encode(sessionId, forKey: AnyStringKey("session_id"))
        try container.encode(seq, forKey: AnyStringKey("seq"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add details to explain how AnyStringKey works?

Comment: CodingKey is just a protocol, and AnyStringKey is just a struct that conforms to it. There's nothing more to it. Is there more to the question?

Comment: What are the Hashable and ExpressibleByStringLiteral for? What's with all the different init functions? Why have intValue but not assign it anywhere? Saying something is just a protocol and something conforms to it is not descriptive about why it works or how it works.

Comment: It's not complex, but if you're curious about how these tools work, see https://youtu.be/-k_vipGhugQ?t=507  I go reasonably deep into CodingKey there (deeper than most people are likely interested in.)

Comment: I can watch that video sure, but I'm also asking for Stack Overflow purposes. A good answer is self-contained with references. So the answer to these questions should be in this answer