# Codable Handle dynamic key at root

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have already seen couple of similar question but I have different JSON

So I have JSON looks like below

```
var json = """
{
"Array1": [
{
"FinancialYear": "17-18"

}],
"Array2": [
{
"FinancialYear": "17-18"
}]
}
"""
```

the issue is **Array1** and **Array2** keys which seems to be dynamic and it is at ROOT and can be more like Array3, Array4 etc

I want to use Codable but because of dynamic key at the root (Array1,Array2) I am not able to get the rid of it.

Here is Struct that I have tried but not working

```
struct CodableJSON: Codable {
    var response:[String:[ArrayInside]]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey   {
        case response = "What should I write here ?" // What should be here ? 
    }

}
```

Comment: I think its not possible. You have to change structure

Comment: Did you check answers on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713638/swift-codable-with-dynamic-keys

Comment: @emrepun Yes I have seen this But If you observe **periods** is root key so there is no issue with that but I have dynamic root key

Comment: @Tobi Thanks comment , Can't be sure. about that. I don't want to bother in future for changes in key. so I am searching for generic solution that can work in all cases as accepted answer provided me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case declare only the `ArrayInside` struct

```
struct ArrayInside: Decodable {
   ...
}
```

and decode the root object as dictionary

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[ArrayInside]].self, from: data)
```

Comment: Yes  ,  That should work !!  I have fixed it with long route , Thanks vadian  you always suggests best