# How to create a Swift model for the JSON file with dynamic key?

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I am trying to write a Swift Codable model for the below JSON.

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "26667" (The problem is here): {
                "pageid": 26667,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Spain",
                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                "pagelanguage": "en",
                "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "en",
                "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
                "touched": "2020-03-14T18:03:48Z",
                "lastrevid": 945549863,
                "length": 254911,
                "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain",
                "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spain&action=edit",
                "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that one of the key changes every time I query.
Marked the in the above JSON as **(The problem is here)**

How to parse the above JSON file with **JSONDecoder**?

This can be easily parsed with libraries like SwiftyJSON.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713638/swift-codable-with-dynamic-keys check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is in making `let pages: [String:Item]` Use

```
// MARK: - Root
struct Root: Codable {
    let batchcomplete: String
    let query: Query
}

// MARK: - Query
struct Query: Codable {
    let pages: [String:Item]
}


// MARK: - Item
struct Item: Codable {
    let pageid, ns: Int
    let title, contentmodel, pagelanguage, pagelanguagehtmlcode: String
    let pagelanguagedir: String
    let touched: Date
    let lastrevid, length: Int
    let fullurl: String
    let editurl: String
    let canonicalurl: String
}
```

---

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```